# Why my flutter moving overflow when screen size increase

Tags: flutter, dart

i have seen a problem in my flutter app which is overflow when screen size increase, how can i solve this solution.
I just used Gridview.builder for printing api product with

```
 childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2),
```

i have attached container full code below, i need to change span count when screen size increased , for example when user screen width increase ( phone user to tab user)

[image: Normal screen when app started]

[image: Error occured when screen siz increased]

```
 Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _getProduct(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data == null) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator(); //const Center(child: Text("Loading"))
                      } else {
                        return LayoutBuilder(
                            builder: (context, constraints) {
                          return GridView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: 4,
                              
                              gridDelegate:
                                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      childAspectRatio:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width /
                                              (MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                      .size
                                                      .height /
                                                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ 180).toInt()),
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                      crossAxisCount: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ 150).toInt()),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          child: Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                              child: Image.network(snapshot
                                                  .data![index].image)),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Expanded(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                  snapshot
                                                      .data![index].name,
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.fade,
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w700),
                                                )),
                                                Text(snapshot
                                                    .data![index].price)
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
                        }
                      );
                    }
                  }
                  
                )
                
              )
```

Comment: It would be nicer if you add some more code. Maybe all content of the Scaffold

Answer (score 0):

You should change `childAspectRatio` accordingly with your widgets height. This might cover it

```
childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 220).toInt()),
```

Comment: @EmreFarukKOLAÇI have changes childAspectRatio  but its getting overflow error, when particular size increased .

Comment: Sorry I cant think a better approach than just changing the 'childAspectRatio' until it fits both tablet and mobile

Comment: You can create a function that can change the child aspect ratio depending on Mediaquery.